# Android: Using 2 ArrayAdapters Error

Tags: android, listview, click, adapter

I now get a new error.

This is my code:

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int i, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), beaconAdap.getItem(i).toString() + " Added to history", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        historyBeacons.add(beaconAdap.getItem(i).toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), HistoryActivity.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("beacons", historyBeacons);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
});
```

}

So i add the int i to an arraylist, i have tested that it goes in and it does. Then a start a new intent for the history activity and send the arraylist over.

This is the code in history:

```
ListView historyLv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.historyView);
ArrayAdapter historyAdap;
ArrayList<String> historyBeacons = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("beacons");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
    historyAdap = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, historyBeacons);
    historyLv.setAdapter(historyAdap);
}
```

But i get this error:

```
03-18 17:44:41.238 18641-18641/nsa.com.museum E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: nsa.com.museum, PID: 18641
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{nsa.com.museum/nsa.com.museum.HistoryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:120)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:151)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:31)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:55)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:33)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:203)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:185)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
                                                                    at nsa.com.museum.HistoryActivity.<init>(HistoryActivity.java:12)
                                                                    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
03-18 17:44:43.362 18846-18846/nsa.com.museum W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/nsa.com.museum-2/lib/x86_64
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: posted the error

Comment: `NullPointerException` means that you are trying to use an object before initialising it. Looks like you are trying to call `setAdapter`on one of your `ListView`s before initialising it.

Comment: my list view i am trying to add to is in another class and layout. DO i have to create a new intent or use shared preferences?

Comment: You have to start the `Activity` in which the `ListView` resides, initialise it and set its adapter with any `List` you need. You may pass the long pressed string to the new `Activity` using the extras mechanism.

Comment: See the update :)

Comment: The `ListView` is not part of the Activity until after the `setContentView` call. Hence initialise it after this call is made.

Comment: Awesome. Problem solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

can You show the erro please 
and I guess you forget to add

```
    ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after you add value to lisy

.........................................................

```
NullPointerException
```

this  erro shows in Android cause you may not Initialized the Adapter
make sure you Initialized the 2nd adapter